# how to copy file unjar it and rename it in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

During docker build process i want to perform following task

1. download zip file using wget
2. copy the zip file to container at say /var/tmp/dest
3. unzip the zip file at dest /var/tmp/dest1  ==> result is say 1 file x.jar
4. copy the x.jar file from /var/tmp/dest1 to root location /

i am able to execute #1 2 and 3 steps but it fails with permission issue on #4
in docker file i am using
RUN cp /var/tmp/dest1/x.jar /

can we copy/or move the file from inside a container from one location to another ?

Here is the dockerfile contents

1. RUN wget --quiet --directory-prefix=/var/tmp/ --no-check-certificate
   artifact-1.zip
2. RUN unzip /var/tmp/artifact-1.zip -d /var/tmp/
3. RUN cp /var/tmp/artifact-*.jar x.jar
4. RUN ls -ld / && ls -latr

Comment: Yes; you may need to switch to `USER root` to set up the filesystem.  Can you provide the actual Dockerfile you're working on and the actual error you get?

Comment: Here is the error
Removing intermediate container d6e135dab01d
 ---> 8e57e54ef95b
Step 6/8 : RUN cp /var/tmp/artifact-*.jar artifact.jar
 ---> Running in c111b221771f
[91mcp: cannot create regular file 'artifact.jar': Permission denied
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c cp /var/tmp/artifact-*.jar artifact.jar' returned a non-zero code: 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure